# How can I make same php file run from many directories in a quick way?

Tags: php, directory, glob, mkdir

In my **books folder** , there are nearly 200 book folder like :

```
--books (folder)  
  |--book1(folder)
  |--book2(folder)
  |--(this continues until 200)
```

What I want is that I need to  create some directories inside 200 folder by fetching data from mysql about folder. I can make it manually but making one by one is very inefficient.

I coded `create_folder.php` and insert it book1 folder to see how it give a result :

```
$current_folder = basename(dirname(__FILE__));

// I choose which directories are inserted.
$sql = "SELECT directory FROM ..............WHERE folder = {$current_folder} ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  mkdir($row['directory']);
}
```

So, in my book1 folder, I created directories via database.
After that, I created `glob.php` file in order to insert `create_folder.php` in all 200 directories automaticly.(I put `glob.php` in main `books folder`. Here :

```
$content = file_get_contents("create_folder.php");

$files = glob( './*' );
foreach( $files as $file ) {
if( is_dir( $file ) && is_writable( $file ) ) {
    file_put_contents( $file . '/create_folder.php', $content );
    }
}
```

Now, inside 200 folders, there is `create_folder.php.` The problem is, I must make `create_folder.php` run in all 200 directories in order to create sub directories. Any quick way to run it? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$files = glob( './*' );
foreach( $files as $file ) {
if( is_dir( $file ) && is_writable( $file ) ) {
$output = exec('php -l '.$file.'/create_folder.php',$function_output,$return);
print $output."\n";
print $return."\n";
var_dump($function_output);
    }
}
```

Run this in your root directory. SO if your sites are in /home/user/site1, /home/user/site2, then run it from /home/user.